# How a function be accessible to various threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am using python 2.7 on windows. I am invoking thread. And in thread class I am using a function.

```py
 hosts = ["https://www.onlinesbi.com/", "https://anking.syndicatebank.in/netbanking/", "https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/",
    "https://www.onlineandhrabank.net.in/", "https://netbanking.canarabank.in/netbanking/RetailLogin.html", "https://www.icicicareers.com/icici_career/probationary-recruitment.html"]
    success=[]
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
      """Threaded Url Grab"""
      def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
      def run(self):
        try:  
            while True:
              #grabs host from queue
              host = self.queue.get()

          # (!) The below call produces the error (!)
          rsp,responsecode = myfunction(host, "GET", False, False)
          if responsecode ==200:
            success.append(host)
            print rsp
            print "----------------------------------%%%%%------"

          #signals to queue job is done
          self.queue.task_done()
    except Exception as e:
           self.queue.task_done()
           print e
start = time.time()
def main():
    try:
  #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance 
      for i in range(3):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

      #populate queue with data   
      for host in hosts:
        queue.put(host)

      #wait on the queue until everything has been processed     
      queue.join()
    except Exception as e:
           print e
main()
print success
print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)**
```

In this **myfunction(host, "GET", False, False)**, I want to use in every thread, but I am getting error as **'module' object is not callable** and the process is not terminating

Comment: This is a typical problem when using [Pokemon Exception Handling](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html), you mask any error including your own (like a SyntaxError). How is `myfunction` defined? According to the error, this is a module and not a function. The full traceback would help here.

Comment: In def myfunction(host, "GET", False, False): I am using ctypes to open a url. So, its a complete function which parse the response and do the necessary stuff from the response. Moreover, I am getting only 'module' object is not callable error on console

Comment: You are getting only the error because you catch the error and tell it to display only the error message. Remove or restrain the `except` clause to get more information or use `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` to get the traceback.